# Pyqt5 widget in grid expansion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qgridlayout

I have a `qgridlayout` that has multiple custom widgets in specific locations like this example below. For an easy example, I am using `qlabels`, but this will show what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

When the user clicks the button at the top, I would like the label with the words "Row 0, Column 0" to expand and take the place of the label below it ("Row 1, Column0"). Also not remove the label below but just hide it. The end result should look like this

[image]

I have been playing around with `setRowStretch` and `setColumnStretch`, but nothing seems to change. This is where I am lost and not sure where I need to go or what I am missing. I have added code for the example in the photos. Thank you for your time and any Help would be greatly appreciated.

**GUI CODE:example.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(191, 136)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_4, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_5, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_6, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row Cover"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row 2, Column 0"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row 1, Column 1"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row 2, Column 1"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row 0, Column 1"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row 0, Column 0"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row 1 ,Column 0 "))
```

**MAIN CODE**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from example import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.MainUi = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.MainUi.setupUi(self)
        self.MainUi.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.expand_row)

    def expand_row(self):
        self.MainUi.label_2.hide()
        self.MainUi.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0,1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle('Example')
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Where Is Nick's answer insufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Try to press the button several times:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#rom example import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(191, 136)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_4, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_5, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_6, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row Cover"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row 2, Column 0"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row 1, Column 1"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row 2, Column 1"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row 0, Column 1"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row 0, Column 0"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row 1 ,Column 0 "))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.MainUi = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.MainUi.setupUi(self)

        self.MainUi.pushButton.setCheckable(True)                           # +++ True
        self.MainUi.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.expand_row)


    def expand_row(self, state):                                            # +++ state
        if state:
            self.MainUi.label_2.hide()
            self.MainUi.gridLayout.addWidget(self.MainUi.label, 1, 0, 2, 1) #  ...2, 1)
        else:
            self.MainUi.gridLayout.addWidget(self.MainUi.label, 1, 0, 1, 1) #  ...1, 1)
            self.MainUi.label_2.show()            

#        self.MainUi.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0,1)  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle('Example')
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry